# TypeError: get_loc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas 2 with the following code:

```py
for time in tfo_dates:
    dt=pd.to_datetime(time)
    indx_time.append(df.index.get_loc(dt,method='nearest'))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: get_loc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

This worked in [version 1.5](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) but if we look at the [version 2 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) there is no method argument anymore.

What method I can use now to get nearest index of timestamp inside time index list?

Comment: So, you want the row within `df` where the index column is closest to `dt`?  You can use `argmin` or `idxmin` for this.  https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-find-the-closest-values-in-a-pandas-series-to-an-input-number/

Comment: yes, I am trying to find row index where df's index is closest to input timestamp.

Comment: `pd.merge_asof` or `numpy.searchsorted` is better for that.

Comment: Thanks Quang, I don't need to merge, just need to find row index with closest value?

Comment: Again, Merge_asof is exactly for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, no need for a loop :

```
matches = df.index.get_indexer(pd.to_datetime(tfo_dates), method="nearest")

out = df.iloc[matches]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                            B
A                            
2023-09-01 17:05:30  0.548814
2023-09-03 13:05:30  0.461479
2023-09-04 23:05:30  0.681820
```

Used inputs :

```
                             B
A                            
2023-09-01 17:05:30  0.548814
2023-09-01 19:05:30  0.715189
2023-09-01 21:05:30  0.602763
2023-09-01 23:05:30  0.544883
2023-09-02 01:05:30  0.423655
...                       ...
2023-09-04 15:05:30  0.617635
2023-09-04 17:05:30  0.612096
2023-09-04 19:05:30  0.616934
2023-09-04 21:05:30  0.943748
2023-09-04 23:05:30  0.681820

[40 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

```
np.random.seed(0)

dtr = pd.date_range("20230901 170530", "20230905 002000", freq="2H")
df = pd.DataFrame({"B": np.random.rand(len(dtr))}, index=pd.Index(dtr, name="A"))

tfo_dates = ["2023-09-01 12:00:00", "2023-09-03 13:00:00", "2023-09-05 14:00:00"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Timeless. Yes your solution work too.

Comment: Why map `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: Was half-asleep, thanks @QuangHoang, updated ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `get_indexer`

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html

The dt (the target) argument in below call, should be an index or a list. It cannot be a single value.

```
df.index.get_indexer(dt,method='nearest')
```

Make a note that, it returns an array object.

Comment: Hi I got an error of TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not iterable. Thanks

Comment: Hi I fixed the above eror by using [dt], so basically, dt (the target) has to be a index or list. it cannot be a single value. Could you please edit your answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: @roudan Thanks for testing. Updated the answer accordingly.